# Why assembly "mov si, bl" wont work?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
.code

main proc

  mov bh, 5
  mov bl, 3

  add bl, bh  
  mov si, bl  ; Why this wont work? How I store something in si?

  invoke ExitProcess, 0

main endp
end main
```

Comment: I don't know why the code look like this here. Sorry I'm a newbie.

Comment: because _si_ is a  16 bit register and bl is 8 bit. try `movsx si, bl` to sign extend _bl_ when placing it in _si_ . If you want the upper bits to be zero you can use `movzx si, bl` (zero extended)

Comment: Should also point out that `movsz` and `movsx` are only available on 386+ , but I made the assumption that since you are using _Irvine32_ that you were targeting 32 bits already.

Comment: Yes!!! It's working thanks a lot Michael. And yes I'm in 32 bits. Thanks for the help.